# UIPageViewController with three UITableViews embedded in Navigation Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipagecontrol

I created three different `UITableViewControllers` that were originally embedded in a `UITabBarController` but I've decided to use a `pageControl` instead. I've deleted the Tab Bar but I am not aware of how to create a pageView 'programmatically' preferably, with three tableviews that have already been created

---

I have worked with pageControl before but only simple things with one view controller and changing the content of that view based on the page control.

---

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController], nil];
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I've also thought of and tried a simple right swipe gesture as a segue, but for some reason it wasn't working. Any help or advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the two required methods of `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`?

Straight from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPageViewController/dataSource):
"To support gesture-based navigation, you must provide your view controllers using a data source object."

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```